# Building a tree structure from list of unique codes in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have list of String values like this...A, A_AChild, A_AChild_furtherChild, A_BChild, A_CChild etc. These value seperated by 'UnderScore' represent that A is parent AChild is its Child and AChild is parent of furtherChild. similary BChild's and CChild's parent is A. I need to create a tree like structure for representation.

```
A
 AChild
  furtherChild
 BChild
 Child
```

How can I achieve this. any algorithm or java program would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought of any approach?

Comment: I couldn't even think of doing it in most general way..:-(

Comment: Then put some pressure on your idle brain. And get it on work. And come up with some approach. Then only someone can help you. Please, do your own homework.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for pointers on how to write questions on SO.  You must show some effort to solve the problem. If this is for a class, and you have no idea how to start, you should ask your professor or teaching assistant.

Comment: I think what we're trying to say is lookup a data structure called "Tree". The keyword is in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a Node and a tree data structure.

```
Node:
Node(String value)


Tree
Tree(Node node) : Creates a tree with root as node

Node getNode(Node node, String nodeToRetrive) nodeToRetrive will be a child of node
returns null if not found

Node addNode(Node node, String nodeToBeAdded) nodeToBeAdded will be added as a new child of node and the newly added Node would be returned
```

Create the tree with root as A.

```
Node root=new Node("A");
Tree tree=new Tree(root);
```

Split the input String into tokens at "_". For example, "A_AChild_furtherChild" would be split into "A","AChild","furtherChild".

```
String s="A_AChild_furtherChild";
String[] tokens=s.split("_");
```

Loop over the tokens starting from the second, in this case "A Child" and do the necessary processing.

```
Node node=tree.root; Node n;
for( i=1 ;i <tokens.length; i++){
  n=getNode(node,tokens[i]);
  if(n==null){
    n=addNode(node,tokens[i]);
  }
  node=n;
}
```

The entire tree can be constructed using the above loop.

Retrieve the values of the nodes in the tree recursively.

```
public void printTree(Node n, int level){
  display level number of spaces and print the value held by Node n.
  for(each of the children of n){
    printTree(theChild, level+1)
  }
}
```

The above recursive method is to be initially invoked in the following way:

```
printTree(root,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on my own..:-)

This is code. I know it may not be efficient :

```
Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        treeSet.add("FEES");
        treeSet.add("FEES_NUSF");
        treeSet.add("FEES_NUSF_NUS1");
        treeSet.add("EXPE");
        treeSet.add("EXPE_NUSE");

        for (String string : treeSet) {


            int splitSize = string.split("_").length;

            if( splitSize > 1 ){
                //log("In if : "+splitSize);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < splitSize; i++) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(string);
                print(sb.toString());
            }
            else{
                print(string);
            }
        }
```